# Error while reversing a stack, can you point it out?

Tags: c++, stack, reverse

Ok, first of all I've written the method, searched stackoverflow beforehand, and noticed my 
idea matched the way most people did it, but, the stack doesn't actually get reversed, but instead weird values are put in it:

I'm doing it like this: I make an auxiliary stack and a while loop with the condition size != 0, and then I call aux.push(pop()) since the pop method also returns the deleted element, so the stack should be reversed, and in O(n) time complexity. But, this happens:

STACK TO BE REVERSED: A C D F -> RESULT:  Đ Đ `

I ran a memory leak tester, it told me I had 4 times tried to free up already freed space, so I'm thinking that might be the cause.

More details:

Stack implemented as dynamic array

Here is the code with the relevant functions:

```
template<typename T>
bool NizStek<T>::push(const T& element){

if(_size == _capacity) increaseCapacity();
if(_size == 0){

    _brojE++;
    _top++;
    _array[_top] = new T(element);

}
else{

    _size++;
    ++_top;
    _array[_top] = new T(element);

}


}
```

POP FUNCTION:

```
template<typename T>
T NizStek<T>::pop(){

if(_size == 0) throw "Stack is empty";
T oldTop = *_array[_top];

delete _array[_top];
_top--;
_size--;

return oldTop;
}
```

Reverse function:

```
 template<typename T>
 void NizStek<T>::reverse() {

NizStek<T> aux;
while(size() != 0){

    aux.push(pop());
}

*this = aux;
}
```

COPY CONSTRUCTOR(OPERATOR = is the same with the first line being delete[] _array;)

```
 template<typename T>
 NizStek<T>::NizStek(const NizStek& rhs){

_size = rhs._size;
_capacity = rhs._capacity;

_niz = new T*[_capacity];

for(int i=0; i<_size ;i++) _array[i] = rhs._array[i];

_top = rhs._top;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't shown us what your copy-constructor looks like ... that is likely where your big problem lies ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't shown it, I'm guessing you are letting the compiler create your copy constructor, which will do a shallow copy.  So this:

```
template<typename T>
void NizStek<T>::reverse()
{
    NizStek<T> aux;
    while(size() != 0)
    {
        aux.push(pop());
    }
    *this = aux; // Potential problem here!
}
```

Will set `this` equal to `aux`'s pointer values.  Presumably, your destructor frees up the memory, so when `aux` goes out of scope, the items pointed to in `this` (`this->_array`) are no longer allocated ... so you get junk when you attempt to dereference them.

You can fix that by writing your own copy-constructor and actually doing a deep copy of the data (or use move semantics).

**EDIT**

With your updated copy constructor, you appear to have another issue:

```
_niz = new T*[_capacity];

for(int i=0; i<_size ;i++) 
    _array[i] = rhs._array[i]; // this is still a shallow copy!

_top = rhs._top;
```

The allocation will create an array of *pointers*, not an array of objects.  So you'll have an array of unassigned pointers (`this` and `aux` will be pointing to the same items, so when `aux` clears them out in its destructor, you are still pointing to junk).  I think what you wanted was

```
_niz = new T[_capacity]; // note the lack of *

for(int i=0; i<_size ;i++) 
    _array[i] = rhs._array[i];

_top = rhs._top;
```

Or

```
_niz = new T*[_capacity];

for(int i=0; i<_size ;i++)
{ 
    _array[i] = new T(*rhs._array[i]); // actually do a deep copy
}

_top = rhs._top;
```

As a side note, if you are concerned about efficiency, you'll probably want to either use a fixed size array, or use a linked-list.  Reallocating and copying the memory buffer every time you push an item that requires a new capacity will be very inefficient for a stack structure.

Comment: I added the constructor, I needed to translate some of the names to english so it took some time :)

Comment: @Matsura in your original post in the push function, i'm assuming you forgot to rename _vrh to _top?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry about that.

Comment: Well in the class attributes I defined array as T** _array, so I had to make a new array of pointers, otherwise I'd get errors while compiling

Comment: The problem with the way you are using the `T**` is that you are copying the pointer values, not what they actually point *to* ... so you end up with the same dangling pointer problem.

Comment: That is it, nice one, the deep copy fixed the problem! Thank you very much, great insight :)
And about efficiency, time efficiency at this time is more important for me than space, still learning.

Comment: If you are concerned about time, you should really consider using a linked-list structure instead of a vector.  You will never have to worry about capacity, nor resizing your memory buffer if you use a linked list, and since a stack can only ever access it's last element, random access is not an issue.

Comment: The C++11 standard introduced the ability to move items in memory instead of having to copy them.  In this particular case, you are creating a local `aux` that will be disposed of at the end of the function, but not before it is copied into `this`.  Instead of doing the copy, you could implement a move-assignment operator to allow the `aux` data to be *given* to `this`.  Alternatively, you could swap the pointers and size values.